# PCAP functions in tcp raw program.

Tags: c, pointers, tcp, network-programming, pcap

I am having some trouble with some functions that won't compile properly. They are pretty much borrowed from an example program to get a better understanding of how network programming works and to see if I could put together a reliable TCP connection (3 way handshake) using RAW sockets. These are the functions:

```
void recieve(u_char *args, const struct pcap_pkthdr *pkthdr, const u_char *buffer)

{

const int one = 1;

u_char *ptr;

int LEN = args;   /* FIRST WARNING POINTS HERE */

struct ipheader *ip;

struct tcpheader *tcp;



ip = (struct ipheader *)(buffer + LEN);

tcp = (struct tcpheader *)(buffer + LEN + sizeof (struct ipheader));



printf("%d\n", LEN);



printf("Packet recieved. ACK number: %d\n", ntohl (tcp->tcph_seqnum));

printf("Packet recieved. SEQ number: %d\n", nthol (tcp->tcph_acknum));

s_seq = nthol (tcp->tcph_seqnum);



send_syn_ack(s_seq, dip, sip, dport, sport);    



sleep(100);

}
```

and

```
void capture()

{

pcap_t *pd;

bpf_u_int32 netmask;

bpf_u_int32 localnet;

char *filter = ("ip dest host %s", dstip);   /* SECOND WARNING POINTS HERE */   

char *dev = NULL;

char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];

struct bpf_program filterprog;

int dl = 0, dl_len = 0;



if ((pd = pcap_open_live(dev, 1514, 1, 500, errbuf)) == NULL)       
    {           

        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open device %s: %s\n", dev, errbuf);

        exit(1);

    }



pcap_lookupnet(dev, &localnet, &netmask, errbuf);

pcap_compile(pd, &filterprog, filter, 0, localnet);

if (pcap_setfilter(pd, &filterprog) == - 1)

    {

        fprintf(stderr, "cannot set pcap filter %s: %s\n", filter, errbuf);

        exit(1);

    }



pcap_freecode(&filterprog);

dl = pcap_datalink(pd);



switch(dl) {

    case 1:

        dl_len = 14;

        break;

    default:

        dl_len = 14;

        break;

}       



if (pcap_loop(pd, -1, recieve, (u_char *)dl_len) < 0) { /* LAST WARNING HERE */

    fprintf(stderr, "cannot get raw packet: %s\n", pcap_geterr(pd));

    exit(1);

}

}
```

and these are the error messages:

```
In function ‘recieve’:
warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
In function ‘capture’:
warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
Warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size
```

I get the first and last warning even in the example program. Are these two functions any good, and is there a simpler and cleaner way to achieve what they are meant to? if not, what should I do to get rid of these warnings? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

u_char is a not a standard type. Equivalent is a uint8_t which is a part of C99 standard. More or less the first error please try,

int LEN = *args

uint8_t is defined in the library stdint.h

In the second error place, do the following,

`char *s = "ip dest host ";

```
char *filter = (char *)malloc(strlen(s) + strlen(dstip) + 1);
strcpy(filter,s);
strcat(filter,dstip);'
```

Please include  for string functions strlen, strcpy and strcat.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the warnings are correct - in `recieve()`, the first argument is `u_char *args`, and in the line you flag, you are attempting to assign `args` to `int LEN`; `args` isn't an `int`, and you're not explicitly asking for it to be converted to an `int`, so the compiler warns about it.

For the second one, I'm not sure what type `dstip` is, since the declaration/definition is not included in the code you posted, but if it's not a `char *`, that would explain the second message.

For the third one, I'd have to know what `pcap_loop()` is expecting in place of the `u_char *` you are passing it, but that's likely also a mismatch.